# How do I dynamically create multiple controls in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I know how to create a list of Controls and add new instances of them to it:

```
private List<FirstCircleControl> Circles = new List<FirstCircleControl>();
FirstCircleControl mc = new FirstCircleControl();
Circles.Add(mc);
```

I want to add a whole bunch of "FirstCircleControls".  How would I add 10 controls to my list?  I want to be able to "create" and then "add" them to the list using a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why you might need to create them all at once and then add them to the list, but here's a solution:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
          .Select(x => new FirstCircleControl())
          .ToList()                        // Forces creation of controls.
          .ForEach(x => Circles.Add(x));   // Adds them to the list.
```

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad. Enumerable looks super handy.